# Find the name and age of the oldest person in a txt file using ruby

Tags: ruby

"Attached is a file with people's names and ages.
There will always be a First name and Last name followed by a colon then the age.
So each line with look something like this.
FirstName LastName: Age

Your job is write a ruby program that can read this file and figure out who the oldest person/people are on this list.  Your program should print out their name(s) and age(s)."

This is the code I have so far:

```
File.open('nameage.txt') do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    line.split(":").last.to_i
    puts line.split(":").last.to_i
  end
end
```

With this, I am able to separate the name from the age but I don't know how to get the highest value and print out the highest value with name and age.
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"figure out who the oldest person/people are on this list", so multiple results are possible. Ruby has a group_by method, which groups an enumerable by a common property. What property? The property you specify in the block.

```
grouped = File.open('nameage.txt') do |f|
  f.group_by do |line|
    line.split(":").last.to_i  # using OP's line
  end
end

p grouped                      # just to see what it looks like    
puts grouped.max.last          # end result
```

Comment: This one is also perfect!!! And so simple! I'm kicking myself for not getting this one! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could push all the ages into an array. Do array.max or sort the array and do array[-1].

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach it:

```
oldest_name = nil
oldest_age = 0
For each line in file do
  split line at the colon and store the age inside age variable
  split line at the colon and store the age inside name variable
  if age is greater than oldest_age then
    oldest_age = age
    oldest_name = name
  end
end
```

finally print the oldest_name and oldest_age

If you're in to one-liners try this

```
$ cat nameage.txt 
John Doe: 34
Tom Jones: 50
Jane Doe: 32
Citizen Kane: 29
$ irb
1.9.3-p551 :001 > IO.read("nameage.txt").split("\n").sort_by { |a| a.split(":")[1].to_i }.last
 => "Tom Jones: 50"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using hash also,

```
hash = {}
File.open('nameage.txt') do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    data = line.split(":")
    hash[data.first] = data.last.strip
  end
  hash.max_by{|k,v| v}.join(" : ")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File.open('nameage.txt') do |handle|
  people = handle.each_line.map { |line| line.split(":") }
  oldest_age = people.map { |_, age| age.to_i }.max

  people.select { |_, age| age.to_i == oldest_age }.each do |name, age|
    puts "#{name}, #{age}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going the right way. Now you just need to store the right things in the right places. I just merged your code and the code proposed by **@oystersauce14**.

```
oldest_name = nil
oldest_age = 0
File.open('nameage.txt') do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    data = line.split(":")
    curr_name = data[0]
    curr_age = data[1].strip.to_i
    if (curr_age > oldest_age) then
      oldest_name = curr_name
      oldest_age = curr_age
    end
  end
end
puts "The oldest person is #{oldest_name} and he/she is #{oldest_age} years old."
```

Notice the use of **String#strip** when acquiring the age. According to the format of the file, this piece of data (the age) has a space before the first number and you need to strip this before converting it using **String#to_i**.

**EDIT:**

Since you may have more than one person with the maximum age in the list, you may do it in two passes:

```
oldest_age = 0
File.open('nameage.txt') do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    curr_age = line.split(":")[1].strip.to_i
    if (curr_age > oldest_age) then
      oldest_age = curr_age
    end
  end
end 
oldest_people = Array.new
File.open('nameage.txt') do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    data = line.split(":")
    curr_name = data[0]
    curr_age = data[1].strip.to_i
    oldest_people.push(curr_name) if (curr_age == oldest_age)
  end
end
oldest_people.each { |person| p "#{person} is #{oldest_age}" }
```

I believe that now this will give you what you need.

Comment: Thank you! While this also worked well, It only put the name and age of ONE of the oldest people. There are actually 3 people with the highest age of 99. But it did give me a way better idea of how to go about it! Thanks again!

Comment: In fact. I'll edit the code to include this situation.

Comment: There it is. Now you have a list with all the oldest people in your list.